# Fill immutable map with for loop upon creation

Tags: scala, dictionary, collections, initialization, immutability

I have this map that looks like this:

```
val fields: Map[(Int, Int), Field]
```

and I thought about doing something like:

```
val fields: Map[(Int, Int), Field] = 
Map(
   for(a <- 0 to 10)
   {
     (0, a) -> new Field(this, 0, a)
   }
)
```

instead of a long copy/paste list like:

```
  (0, 0) -> new Field(this, 0, 0),
  (1, 0) -> new Field(this, 1, 0),
  (2, 0) -> new Field(this, 2, 0),
  (3, 0) -> new Field(this, 3, 0),
  (4, 0) -> new Field(this, 4, 0),
  (5, 0) -> new Field(this, 5, 0),
  (6, 0) -> new Field(this, 6, 0),
  (7, 0) -> new Field(this, 7, 0),
  (8, 0) -> new Field(this, 8, 0),

  (0, 1) -> new Field(this, 0, 1), ...
```

But I get

> Type mismatch, expected: (NotInferedA, NotInferedB), actual: Unit

Why is this and how can I overcome this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your for comprehension doesn't return anything.
Here are two different solutions to your problem. I personally would prefer the second one.

```
case class Field(map: Map[(Int, Int), Field], a: Int, b: Int)

val fields: Map[(Int, Int), Field] = 
Map(
   (for(a <- 0 to 10) yield (0, a) -> new Field(fields, 0, a)): _*
)

val fields: Map[(Int, Int), Field] =
  (0 to 10).map(a => (0, a) -> new Field(fields, 0, a)).toMap
```

edit:

```
case class Field(board: Board, x: Int, y: Int)
class Board {
  val fields: Map[(Int, Int), Field] =
    (0 to 10).map(a => (0, a) -> new Field(this, 0, a)).toMap
}
```

```
class Board {
  val fields: Map[(Int, Int), Field] =
    (for(a <- 0 to 10; b <- 0 to 10)
        yield (a, b) -> new Field(this, a, b)).toMap
}
```

Comment: A great answer. But I have a problem with it... The constructor for a Field is (Board, x: Int, y: Int) and I want to create the fields (Map) in the Board class. If I do Map((0 to 10)...) I get a problem because "this" refers to the map then, while I'd need a Board for the new Field. The first version works tho. So many thanks!

Comment: Why would `this` refer to the map? Look at my second example. It seems to work fine.

Comment: Ya, that was my mistake. Now I only need to figure out how to do this with (a, b), so with two loops/iteration

Comment: I added another example.

Comment: Ya, thanks, with a for-comprehensions it's no problem. I thought maybe the "nicer" solution you posted was possible with two loops, but I found no way to do it and still look nice :)