# `this` Type in Scala

Tags: scala

Looking at this question, [Fill immutable map with for loop upon creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30561653/fill-immutable-map-with-for-loop-upon-creation), I was curious as to what `this` means in `Map(1 -> this)`.

```
scala> Map(1 -> this)
res6: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,type] = Map(1 -> @53e28097)

scala> res6(1)
res7: type = @53e28097
```

I have not seen `type` before as a type.

What is it?

Comment: +1, because although I initially thought this would be a simple "it's just a reference to the current scope" answer, I've been completely able to figure out what it is for myself. This is not helped by how hard it is to google what "this" is in Scala.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to work a bit odd in the REPL, but if you actually compile or interpret a script, `this` does indeed seem to point to the current instance of the enclosing object.

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.{ universe => ru }

object Main {
  def getType[T : ru.TypeTag](instance: T) = ru.typeOf[T]

  def sayHello = println("hello!")

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(this.getType(123)) // Prints "Int"
    this.sayHello              // Prints "hello!" to the console

    getType(this).decls foreach println _
    // Prints the following outputs to the console:
    // constructor Main
    // method getType
    // method sayHello
    // method main
  }
}
```

As for why it does not exhibit this behavior in the REPL, I'm not sure.

Comment: "As for why it does not exhibit this behavior in the REPL, I'm not sure". It does. Try to paste your code in the REPL and then do `Main.main(Array.empty)`, you'll get the same result (in other words, `thid` will refer to `Main` in the REPL too) . However, if you reference `this` in a top level declaration in the REPL, `this` will actually refer to the enclosing class/object, which in this case happens to be a wrapper object created by the REPL to host your declaration (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549174/trying-to-understand-how-classes-declared-on-the-repl-are-treated-internally)

Comment: As for where the `type` is coming, my (pure speculative) guess is that it comes from the REPL trying to cleanup the actual type. Because the code is in a wrapper object named something like `$iw`, when you declare a class/trait `Foo` in the repl, the actual type will be something like `iw.Foo`, but you really don't wanna know about `$iw` so the REPL removes the `$iw` prefix and prints just `Foo`. In OP's case, `this` has type `$iw.type`, so removing `$iw` just leaves `type`, which unfortunately is not an actual type. So that would be just a corner case of the REPL trying to be nice with you.